# IE doesn't render background image

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background-image, background-size

I have a banner on the top of a webpage, using the background css tag on a header element.

HTML:

```
<section class="page-wrapper">
    <header class="block"></header>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <footer></footer>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.page-wrapper > header {
  background: url('/path/to/image.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
}
```

And another CSS rule used for sticky footer. Not sure if it's relevant, but i'll add it here, just in case:

```
.block {
  display: table-row;
}
```

This works just fine in Chrome and Firefox. But in Internet Explorer 11 and 10, it sometimes fails to render. But when I hover the cursor over a menu item, it renders under that element only. When I say 'sometimes', I mean I can hammer the F5 key 30 times, and it sometimes it renderes, and sometimes it doesn't. It appears to me to be random.

I have tried changing the name of the image, to rule out any caching issues.

Tried it on three seperate computers in both IE 11 and 10.

Can't seem to post the screenshots I have as embedded, need at least 10 reputation. So I'll link to imgur instead.

Working: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOFhb.jpg

Problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEIMt.jpg

Anyone experienced something like this?

Edit: added the live site URL in the comments. Can't add more links in the original post.

Comment: We can't tell without a demo but it looks like it's a system error rather than a CSS one. I am curious why you are using `display:table row` though.

Comment: The site in question is live. But I am reluctant to give out it's URL. My first thought was system error also, as it was tested on a windows Server 2008 session. But tried it on two other computers aswell (locally), with the same result.

I'm using this [trick](http://galengidman.com/2014/03/25/responsive-flexible-height-sticky-footers-in-css/) to get sticky footer on the site. That's where the `display:table row` comes from

Comment: Well you could make a reduced case in JsFiddle.net with minimal code enough to show the issue.

Comment: I'll give it a go. Will report back.

Comment: As it stands now, the question lacks necessary information. A fiddle or self-hosted demo (or live-site link) would be necessary to reduce this issue.

Comment: Haven't been able to create representable demo in jsfiddle. So we'll try the live site instead. In the form of a goo.gl URL: [http://goo.gl/lc9ihz](http://goo.gl/lc9ihz)

Comment: Used a VM from this [site](https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads) to reproduce the issue in IE10 (windows 7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Paulie_D mentions, it seems `display:table-row` is the sinner. Tried removing it, and that seemed to fix it. I didn't try it earlier since I was conviced it was needed in the sticky footer solution. However the sticky footer is still working even after removing the table-row tag. Thanks for all your help and input.